# What global hook can be used to prevent overrides to a non-client area of a window?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, winapi, windows-shell

My goal is to prevent insertion of the button (circled in red) into the system menu of a process:

[image]

I do not control this process so I cannot modify it from within.

I was thinking to create a DLL [with a global hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50397/System-Wide-Hooking-for-the-WM-CHAR-Message) and trap and reroute the following messages to be processed by the OS instead of the process itself: `WM_NCPAINT`, `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_NCHITTEST`, `WM_NCACTIVATE` (the opposite sequence to what is [described here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-titlebar).)

I can isolate the window of this process by its class name `Chrome_WidgetWin_1` but I wasn't sure [which hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx) to use to reroute the messages?

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible in a global hook. You can't reroute messages like you describe.  You would have to inject code into the target process itself and have that code subclass the target `HWND` directly, then it can pass relevant messages directly to `DefWindowProc()`, bypassing the window's native message handler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Appreciate it!